# How restrict viewing items on SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am a beginner in SharePoint and is currently in the process of developing a SharePoint site for leave requests, my problem and the next I have a list called off request in which you can create new equest but I have several users and I want only the author of each item created that can be seen in the list, how to restrict viewing list items.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In list settings, click Advance Settings, in Item-level permission, select the "Read items that were created by the user"

Comment: I have already tried this method but no change in the list, all users get to see, I do not know if I need to change something else thank you

Comment: Create a View that will show only the items you created. and put it as default view.